# Gradle behind proxy with no Authentication

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I am running gradle (version 2.5) behind a proxy server which does not require authentication. I have set the following in gradle.properties

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=rilproxy.in.ril.com
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
```

However I am getting the following exception which complains that proxy server requires authentication. Does gradle expect some dummy value in case there is no proxyUser and proxyPassword. I have confirmed with dont have any authentication credentials for proxy server and this is working fine if I set the same for Ivy build.

```
Parallel execution with configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9.
     Required by:
         :liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2:unspecified
      > Could not resolve commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9.
         > Could not get resource 'http://cdn.repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com
mons-codec/commons-codec/1.9/commons-codec-1.9.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://cdn.repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public/commons-c
odec/commons-codec/1.9/commons-codec-1.9.pom'. Received status code 407 from server: Proxy Authentic
ation Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Prox
y filter is denied.  )
```

Comment: gradle does not require you to add dummy credentials. for some reason it seems the proxy setup is not picked up. where did you put your gradle.properties file?

Comment: I am using something called Liferay portal which is having gradle setup. The properties is in liferay developments home directory. It is definitely reading from property file because when I dont proving proxy details in gradle.properties, it simply rejects saying connection refused. When I specify proxy details it gives me 407 error. I suspect it may be something with Windows TMG but I am not sure.